# How can I run background services in react native without keeping it in a loop?

Tags: react-native, npm, background-service

Can anyone tell me how to run background services in react native without looping it?

I want to run a background service in react native. But all the packages I've used use a loop to keep the services running in the background. Because of the loop some of the variables I use change. So, I want to keep the background services without looping. I tried with different npm packages like react-native-background-actions, react-native-background-task.

```
const veryIntensiveTask = async taskDataArguments => {
  const { delay, runActivity } = taskDataArguments;
  await new Promise(async resolve => {
    for (let i = 0; BackgroundJob.isRunning(); i++) {
      await sleep(delay);
      runActivity();
    }
  });
};
await BackgroundJob.start(veryIntensiveTask, options1);
```

It would be great if someone could provide a way to run background services in react native without looping it or provide a correct example code with these packages.

Comment: How you are using `react-native-background-actions` , code is required for further explaination

Comment: @Navitas28
`const veryIntensiveTask = async taskDataArguments => {
 const { delay, runActivity } = taskDataArguments;
 await new Promise(async resolve => {
 for (let i = 0; BackgroundJob.isRunning(); i++) {
 await sleep(delay);
 runActivity();
  });
};`

`await BackgroundJob.start(veryIntensiveTask, options1);`

Comment: [Screenshot of the code](https://i.postimg.cc/zfWbt1s3/Screenshot-2023-05-27-103746.png)

Comment: Please update your question an put the code as **text** inside code blocks